# C# Property reference type?

Tags: c#

I'm starting out in C# and I have a question.

Say I have an object:

```
Person
```

and a property on Person called Cat:

```
Person.Cat
```

If I do:

```
Cat cat = new Cat(stuff);
cat.Name = "Alan";
Person.Cat = cat;
```

Is Cat a direct reference to cat?
If I do:

```
Person.Cat.Name = "John";
```

Will cat's Name be "John"?

Because I think I tried doing something like this before, and I got NullReferenceException or something like that.

Comment: What happens you try it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with XNA. You should remove that tag, if possible.

Comment: Your `NullReferenceException` may have occurred because your program hadn't yet assigned a value to `Person.Cat`.

Answer (score 5):

If 'cat' is a class, i.e., a reference type, than a copy of that reference will be stored in person.Cat.  That means that changes made to properties of 'cat' will be reflected in person.Cat.  However, since it is a copy of the original reference, the behavior is like so:

```
Cat cat = new Cat(stuff);
cat.Name = "Alan";
Person.Cat = cat;
cat.Name = "Will";  //Person.Cat.Name is now "Will"
cat = new Cat(stuff);
cat.Name = "Greg";  
// Person.Cat is still named "Will".  
// The original reference now points  to a different object on the heap than does Person.Cat.
```

if Cat is a value type, then a copy is made upon assignment and changes in one will not reflect in the other (of course, a struct could have a reference type property or public field, but you get the idea).

Comment: Also note that structs are value types, so for those, a copy is made instead of a reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, assuming your full code is something like this:

```
// Person class.
public class Person {

    // Automatic property.
    public Cat Cat { get; set; }

}

// Cat class (not a struct!).
public class Cat {

    // Automatic property.
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

In this case, accessing `myPerson.Cat` will give you a direct reference to that object. You can call methods on it, access its properties, pass it into a method that accepts a `Cat` parameter, whatever you like.

However, in this situation you have no certainty that the `myPerson.Cat` property is not `null`. Any code could set it to be any object of type `Cat`, or `null`. If something has set it to `null` and you try to access `myPerson.Cat.Name`, you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

In order to avoid getting those exceptions, you should always verify that the property is not null through an explicit check like  `if (myPerson.Cat != null) { ... }` before using it. You can skip this step if you know *for sure* that it can never be `null`, and that nothing can violate this assumption. You may want to look into using [code contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/contracts) to ensure this in the future when you're more comfortable with the language.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Cat a direct reference to cat?

Yes. For example:

```
var cat = new Cat(stuff);
cat.Name = "Alan";
Person.Cat = cat;
cat.Name = "George";
var nowCalledGeorge = Person.Cat.Name;
```

So the answer to this question

> Will cat's Name be "John"?

is yes.